# UITabBarController "want full screen" setting

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

In IB for an UITabBarController, there is a setting for each view controller for each tab that called "want full screen".  The book I am reading says that if you want to display your view in full screen then select that option.  But you will need to have away to get back to your tab bar.  Unfortunately, this book does not have any samples that use this setting.  And I have tried myself but when I tapped on the tap bar the resulted view is not full screen.  Any one know how to use it properly?

Comment: this is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373791/fullscreen-uiview-with-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-overlay-on-the-top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wantsFullScreenLayout property of UIViewController, is used to *hide the status bar and navigation bar*, and *place your view from the screen top* instead of really making UIViewController full screen.

That is, when `wantsFullScreenLayout` set to `YES`, your origin point (0, 0) of your view controller's view will be the same point as the top left corner of status bar.

Thus, this property is usually used with translucent status bar.

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL wantsFullScreenLayout
```

For example, Photo.app in iOS uses this property to show thumbnails.

[image: http://images.apple.com/tw/iphone/features/images/photos-togo-20100607.jpg]