# Hiding the status bar leaves a white space

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Hiding the status bar leaves a white space that I do not know how to remove.

The code I use is noted below, I have tried putting it in different places with no luck.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{    
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: See the answers to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373791/fullscreen-uiview-with-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-overlay-on-the-top

Comment: Didn't work, still have the white space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to do these steps:

1. Go into the interface builder. Click on your view, and on the right interface bar, select the option from the dropdown menu:
   Status Bar> None
2. Drag the rest of your things on your view up or whatever occupies the top of your view to account for the visible white space.

Now that the status bar in the interface builder is gone, you are able to account for it when you hide it programmatically.

Comment: Some reason this still didn't fix the issue for me. I had to add "[self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES]"