# ios translucent navigation bar but solid navigation bar buttons

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to create this effect
[Fullscreen UIView with Status bar and Navigation Bar overlay on the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373791/fullscreen-uiview-with-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-overlay-on-the-top)

where the navigation bar is translucent, but the navigation bar buttons are solid.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = .3;
```

This automatically makes the buttons translucent too. What's a workaround to make the buttons have a solid color?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Get id of your second line of code: `self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = .3;`
and the navigation bar will be translucent and it will "appear" like the buttons are solid, but it's just a "translucent" button on top of a "translucent" bar, giving the illusion of a solid button.

You won't be able to go lighter (.3) than the norm, unless you want to use images instead.

Comment: How can I make the navigation bar more translucent than it is though? I want to make it very light..so it gives a nice contrast with the dark buttons on top

Comment: I have a question related to this but don't want to ask a question if it can be answered quickly; I'm setting the NC's alpha to 0 for a tabBarController (which has its own NCs)... When I pop back to the root from my tabBar, the bar's alpha remains zero when I try to reset it with self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha in loadView and/or viewDidLoad...